# Creating an associated record from within the model with .create fails with no method for nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So Im really struggling to get this right... Basically what I want do is when a Procedure record is saved or created I want to check if the status is set to completed. And then if it is then to go ahead and create an associated transaction record with details from the Procedure record.
But I keep getting a `*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method`create' for nil:NilClass"`

Just not sure where to go!!

```
class Procedure < ActiveRecord::Base
store_accessor :properties, :tooth, :buccal, :mesial, :occlusal, :distal, :lingual

belongs_to :item
belongs_to :patient
belongs_to :practice
belongs_to :provider
belongs_to :operatory
belongs_to :appointment 
belongs_to :transaction

before_create :create_transaction
before_save :create_transaction
before_save :check_if_was_marked_as_complete

validates :item, :patient, :provider, :date, presence: true
validates_associated :item, :patient,  :provider


private

def create_transaction
      if status == "completed"
        transaction.create do |t|
          t.amount = fee
          #t.practice = self.practice
          t.debit_account = patient.family.account
          t.credit_account = provider.revenue_account
          #t.patient = self.patient
         end
   end
end

def check_if_was_marked_as_complete
    if self.status_was == "completed"
        return false
    else
        return true
    end     
end
end
```

***EDIT**** My method now looks like this

```
def create_association
 if status == "completed"
  create_transaction do |t|
    t.amount = fee
    #t.practice = self.practice
    t.debit_account = patient.family.account
    t.credit_account = provider.revenue_account
    #t.patient = self.patient
  end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction is `nil` until it exists. So `procedure.transaction #=> nil` and `nil.create #=> undefined method create for nil`.

To build an associated object in a belongs_to association, you have the following methods:

- build_association
- create_association
- create_association!

Replace  by your associated object (i.e build_transaction, create_transaction etc.)

First thing you should do is to rename your callback `create_association` because this method is still defined by Rails.

Then in your callback:

```
create_transaction do |t|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you help I think I am on the right course but the associated record still isn't being created... this is what I have changed my method to:
def create_association
    if status == "completed"
      create_transaction do |t|
        t.amount = fee
        #t.practice = self.practice
        t.debit_account = patient.family.account
        t.credit_account = provider.revenue_account
        #t.patient = self.patient
      end
   end
end

Comment: delba thanks for you help!! turns out my error after I took your advice was because I wasn't meeting the validation requirements on the Transactions model but that's all fixed now and she is working beautifully thanks for all our help!!